# Additonal sign up fields in devise (rails) do not get repopulated after a failed submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using devise in rails as my user system.

I have several extra fields on sign up, for example - `:first_name` as well as email and password.

I'm using `devise_parameter_sanitizer` in the application controller and allowing `:first_name` to be saved. This all works correctly and the user can sign up with all the extra fields.

However I have an issue when the form is invalid (for example the password and password confirmation do not match), the user submits with form with the first name field filled in. When the invalid form is return the first name fields data has been lost.

How do I make it so devise keeps these extra sign up fields filled in after an invalid submit, the user is has to re-enter details otherwise.

Thanks.

Edit - The controller is all taken care of by devise. And the form is the one that comes with devise plus some extra fields. I've added this to the application controller as a before action to save extra params:

```
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |u|
      u.permit(
        :email, :password, :first_name
      )
    end
  end
```

The view is the same as the devise one, but with additional inputs. The extra fields are saving fine, they're just wiped when an invalid for is returned, as above. Thanks again.

Comment: it'd be helpful to see what you're doing in the controller and view

Comment: The controller is all taken care of by devise. I've added some more details.

Comment: Are you willing to customize the controller?

Comment: Yeah, willing to create a new controller to handle this.

Comment: Your code works fine on a new project. I created a repo for you to check https://gitlab.com/stbn/stack-devise may be a minor configuration is missing on your project

Answer (score 0):

In your `#create` method in the registration controller you need to have `@user = User.new(...)` then `render :new`. And in your view (the form), you need something like `form_for @user` (if not, also need `@user = User.new` in your `#new` method in your controller)

Comment: I don't have a registrations controller. That's all taken care of by devise.

Comment: You may need to override your Devise's registration controller